# Question about notation in group theory

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, notation

If you click on the link below you will find a theorem from Daniel Gorenstein's book "Finite Groups". I am not sure what is the meaning of the i'(x). What does the ' mean?

http://prnt.sc/as5413

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would we click on some random external link? Can't you quote the theorem?

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I didn't realize it would be an issue, I was trying to include an image of the theorem but apparently I don't have enough reputation to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In general if $H$ is not normal then $y_ix$ cannot be written $hy_i$ for any $h\in H$. But it may be written $hy_{i'}$ for some other $i'$, since $G = \bigcup_j Hy_j$.

Then this $i'$ and this $h$ depend on $x$ and $i$ : you can write $y_ix = hy_i' = h_i(x)y_{i'(x)}$.

Comment: So if i belongs to [1,n] does it mean that i' is simply some element in [1,n], but not necessarily i = i'

Comment: Yes, and it depends on $x$ and $i$.

Comment: OK thank you very much